# Searching google news articles Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-news

im currently thinking about writing about a script which is looking out for new articles from google news search.
So I want to download the first 10-20 articles and safe it into a folder.
Best would be only the main text not the whole html file.

So as an example:
Searchterm "FC Barcelona"
Folder "01.01.2020" articles in here

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the Google News RSS feed. It is already formatted in a easy to parse format. You can perform a search using the following format.

`https://news.google.com/rss/search?{query}` where query can be `q=keywords` so for your example searching for `Searchterm "FC Barcelona"`. The query must be urlencoded. Which can be done with Python

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
query = urlencode({'q': 'Searchterm "FC Barcelona"'})
url = "https://news.google.com/rss/search?" + query

# make requests
resp = requests.get(url)
# parse request
```

Then you can parse the feed as you liked and place the data into folders.

Comment: Thanks a lot! looks great